# Sets question confusion..

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Q. Using the properties of sets show that $A\cup(A\cap B)=A$

***Answer*** Since $A\subseteq B$ then $A\cap B = B$

Also $A\cap B\subseteq A$. So $A\cup(A\cap B)=A$

**Things I dont understand:**

I imagine $A\subseteq B$ as a cirle 'A' within a bigger circle 'B' so if $A\cap B = B$ how can $A\cap B $ be a subset of A shouldnt A be a subset of $A\cap B $ since A is smaller than B and we just proved $A\cap B $ equals B. Also how did they drive the last line - $A\cup(A\cap B)=A$

Comment: It seems to be a typo in the answer - $A \cap B = A$.

Comment: Note: $A\cup(A\cap B)\equiv(A\cup A)\cap(A\cup B)\equiv A\cap(A\cup B)\equiv A$.

Comment: I would say, clearly $A\cap B\subseteq A$, so $A\cup(A\cap B)\subseteq A\cup A=A$. Then, $A\subseteq A\cup C$ for any set $C$, so $A\subseteq A\cup(A\cap B)$.

Comment: You left out the premise that $A \subset B$.  The statement is true whether $A$ is or is not a subset.  $A \cap B \subset A$ so $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$.

Comment: First of all "Since $A \subset B$"  Sez who?  That was never stated or given.  Second the $A\cap B = B$.  That is false (unless $A = B$).  If $A \subset B$ then $A \cap B =A$ precisely for the reason you gave.  Thirdly "Also $A \cap B \subset A$".  That is the ONLY thing that matters.  It doesn't matter if $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$ or neither.  $A\cap B \subset A$ so $A \cup (subset A) = A$.

Comment: $A \cap X$ is *always* a subset of $A$.  *always*.  So if $A \cap B = B$ then $B = A\cap B \subset A$.  But the statement that $A \subset B \implies A\cap B = B$ is completely false.  They either mean $A\subset B\implies A\cap B=A$ or $B\subset A\implies A\cap B=B$.  But *NEITHER* matter and for all we care BOTH might as well be FALSE, as $A\cap B\subset A$.  *ALWAYS*.

Comment: Can you type what the *actual* question was?  That is obviously not the correct answer for the question as you typed it.

Comment: $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$ always.  And $B \cup (A \cap B) = B$ always.  It makes no difference if $A \subset B; B \subset A; A = B;$ or $A\not \subset B \land B \not \subset A$.

Comment: @fleablood yes it should be what you said, turns out it was a typo in the answer they gave